# How to validate an object inside a JSON schema in Karate whether its empty or contains a series of key:value pairs?

Tags: karate

I am trying to validate an API response using Karate for either of these two states.
Scenario 1 (when it returns a `contractData` object that contains a fee key):

```json
{
    "customer": {
        "financialData": {
            "totalAmount": 55736.51,
            "CreateDate": "2022-04-01",
            "RequestedBy": "user1@test.com"
        },
        "contractData": {
            "Fee": 78.00
        }
    }
}
```

Scenario 2 (when it returns an empty `contractData` object):

```json
{
    "customer": {
        "financialData": {
            "totalAmount": 55736.51,
            "CreateDate": "2022-04-01",
            "RequestedBy": "user1@test.com"
        },
        "contractData": {}
    }
}
```

How can I write my schema validation logic to validate both states?
The best thing I could have done is to write it like this:

```
* def schema = {"customer":{"financialData":{"totalAmount":"#number","CreateDate":"#?isValidDate(_)","RequestedBy":"#string"},"contractData":{"Fee": ##number}}}
* match response == schema
```

And it seems like it works for both above scenarios, but I am not sure whether this is the best approach or not. Problem with this approach is if I have more than one key:value pair inside `contractData` object and I want to be sure all those keys are present in there when it is not empty, I cannot check it via this approach because for each individual key:value pair, this approach assumes that they could either be present or not and will match the schema even if some of those keys will be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I have to admit I've never come across this case ever, and that's saying something. I finally was able to figure out a possible solution:

```
* def chunk = { foo: 'bar' }
* def valid = function(x){ return karate.match(x, {}).pass || karate.match(x, chunk).pass }
* def schema = { hey: '#? valid(_)' }
* def response1 = { hey: { foo: 'bar' } }
* def response2 = { hey: { } }
* match response1 == schema
* match response2 == schema
```

Answer (score 1):

I've come to similar case but with `null` instead of `empty`.
Here is my solution translated to your problem:

```
* def expected = 
"""
{
    "customer": {
        "financialData": {
            "totalAmount": 55736.51,
            "CreateDate": "2022-04-01",
            "RequestedBy": "user1@test.com"
        },
        "contractData": "#object"
    }
}
"""
* def contractDataExpected = "contractData": {"Fee": "#number"}
* def isContractDataNullOrObject = (response.contractData == null) || (typeof response.contractData == 'contractDataExpected')
* match isContractDataNullOrObject == true
```